# 2 column absolute layout need both to be 100% height

Tags: html, css

I've simplified the layout below to show what I mean. Both columns need to be 100% but the problem is if 1 column has content in it that stretches it below the 100% height causing scrollbars, then the other will remain 100% height of window. Is there a way to ensure both divs always take up the entire height of the document? If you work with the html below you will see that when you scroll down, the left column height remains at the original height of the window. Is there a solution to this without javascript? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
<style>
    html,body {
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .column {
        min-height: 100%;
        background: red;
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
    }

    #left {

        left: 100px;
    }

    #right {
        left: 400px;
    }

    #content {
        /* This height will be unknown. 2000px is just for example to push right column down*/
                height: 2000px;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="left" class="column"></div>
<div id="right" class="column">
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Css-

```
.column {
        height: 100%;
        background: red;
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
    }

#left {

    left: 100px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
}

#right {
    left: 400px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
}
```

Working Fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/vR4eU/

And why this works:

We make both the div's look very long by adding the padding-bottom: 1000px and then trick the browser that it isnt true by using margin-bottom: -1000px. See this [blog](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61) that better explains the solution.

---

**Update:** Probably `Faux columns` is a better cross browser compatible way that can help you. See this- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

Comment: This works if you know the height of content but I need it to adjust to different heights. the 2000px height on content was just to push right column down

Comment: May be I dint get you right, but you wanted both the divs to be of same height even if your contents in one column keep exceeding the 100% height of the window. Am I right?

Comment: Looking at your comment on an other solution, I think you mean that the right column's content should not exceed the 100% height. Is it?

Comment: Yes your first comment is correct. Second one no. The height of contents is unknown but I do want the window to be able to scroll, and also left column needs to be same height

Comment: Thanks that had come to mind but it would mean changing the layout quite a bit. I've just gone with the javascript option.

Answer (score 0):

If its just the content pushing the height, you could solve it by either setting it as a max-height: 100% or give it overflow: hidden to stop it happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
<style>
body, html {
  height: 100%; /* make it fill up the screen, when content longer than 100%, will cause overflow as expected */
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%; /* we don't want overflow in this layer. so make it flexible */
  position: relative;
}

.column {
  border: 4px red dashed; /* to see the moving of the block when scroll. */
  width: 200px;
}

#left {
  /* this need to be always the same height of .wrapper, which is at least 100% in height. */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;       
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100px;
}

#content {
  /* this can have any height you want it will change the height of .wrapper when it grows. but you can't use percent unit! */
  margin-left: 400px;
  min-height: 600px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="left" class="column"></div>
  <div id="content" class="column"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This should work on all the modern browsers (IE7 may not work with this version for it doesn't support min-height, through it works fine in IE9's IE7 mode. check out the [previous one](http://jsfiddle.net/vR4eU/2/)). This solution make the left column always keep the height of the `.wrapper`, which will automatically fit the height for content inside, and maintain a least height of 100% no matter what the height of `#content` is.

view the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vR4eU/4/).

If you need some visual effect like showing a background or a border on right, to make the content looks like stretched up to at least 100% in height. You may use another decorating box, like `#left` and make it lying behind `#content`. Which visually satisfied your need, and you don't have to write any script XD. enjoy

view the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vR4eU/6/) for this.

Comment: Thanks its almost there. Problem is it always needs to be 100% height of the document. In your solution if content get set to 10px height the columns will wrap to that height

Comment: @uguMark 'perfect' solution provided.